# Laravel assert redirect with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel, tdd, assert

I am newly trying out TDD with laravel, and I want to assert if a redirect took a user to a url that has an integer param.
I wonder if I could use regex to catch all positive integers.

I'm running this app with the laravel 5.8 framework and I know that the url parameter is 1 because I refresh the database each for each test, so setting the redirect url as `/projects/1` works but this sort of hardcoding feels weird.

I've attached a block of code I tried using regex for but this doesn't work

```
 /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_create_projects()
    {
        // $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        //If i am logged in
        $this->signIn(); // A helper fxn in the model

        //If i hit the create url, i get a page there
        $this->get('/projects/create')->assertStatus(200);

        // Assumming the form is ready, if i get the form data
        $attributes = [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];

        //If we submit the form data, check that we get redirected to the projects path
        //$this->post('/projects', $attributes)->assertRedirect('/projects/1');// Currently working
        $this->post('/projects', $attributes)->assertRedirect('/^projects/\d+');

        // check that the database has the data we just submitted
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('projects', $attributes);

        // Check that we the title of the project gets rendered on the projects page 
        $this->get('/projects')->assertSee($attributes['title']);

    }
```

I expected the test to treat the argument in `assertRedirect('/^projects/\d+');` as regex and then pass for any url like `/projects/1` so far it ends in a number, but it takes it as a raw string and expects a url of `/^projects/\d+`

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you can get newly created ID using $this->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$.id');

Comment: @Mack4Hack this didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After watching a tutorial by Jeffery Way, he talked about handling this issue.
Here's how he solves the situation

```
//If we submit the form data, 
$response = $this->post('/projects', $attributes);

//Get the project we just created
$project = \App\Project::where($attributes)->first();

// Check that we get redirected to the project's path
$response->assertRedirect('/projects/'.$project->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by now. You need to test the `Location` header in the response with a regular expression.

This is a problem because you cann't use the current route name. That's why I did two functions that bring a little bit of readability to your test. You will use this function like this:

```php
// This will redirect to some route with an numeric ID in the URL.
$response = $this->post(route('groups.create'), [...]);

$this->assertResponseRedirectTo(
    $response,
    $this->prepareRoute('group.detail', '[0-9]+'),
);
```

This is the implementation.

```php
/**
 * Assert whether the response is redirecting to a given URI that match the pattern.
 */
public function assertResponseRedirectTo(Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse\TestResponse $response, string $url): void
{
    $lastOne = $this->oldURL ?: $url;
    $this->oldURL = null;

    $newLocation = $response->headers->get('Location');

    $this->assertEquals(
        1,
        preg_match($url, $newLocation),
        sprintf('Should redirect to %s, but got: %s', $lastOne, $newLocation),
    );
}

/**
 * Build the pattern that match the given URL.
 * 
 * @param mixed $params
 */
public function prepareRoute(string $name, $params): string
{
    if (! is_array($params)) {
        $params = [$params];
    }

    $prefix = 'lovephp';
    $rep = sprintf('%s$&%s', $prefix, $prefix);
    $valuesToReplace = [];

    foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
        $valuesToReplace[$index] = str_replace('$&', $index . '', $rep);
    }

    $url = preg_quote(route($name, $valuesToReplace), '/');
    $this->oldURL = route($name, $params);

    foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
        $url = str_replace(
            sprintf('%s%s%s', $prefix, $index, $prefix),
            $param,
            $url,
        );
    }

    return sprintf('/%s/', $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Location` value from the response headers, and match it that way

```php
$this->assertMatchesRegularExpression(
  '#/^projects/\d+#', 
  $response->headers->get('Location')
);
```